The terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}^\to$.
This is part of Exercise 3.6.2 of Goldblatt's "Topoi".
Recall that $\mathbf{Set}^\to$ is the category with objects functions $f:A\to B$ and arrows pairs $\langle h,k\rangle: f\to g$ of functions such that
$\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD}
A @>h>> C\\
@VfVV @VVgV\\
B @>>k> D
\end{CD}$$
commutes.
The Question:

Find the terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}^\to$.

Thoughts:
I think it is, up to isomorphism,
$$\operatorname{id}_*:\{*\}\to \{*\};$$
that is, the function from a singleton set to itself.
Why? Well, there appears to be only one arrow from an arbitrary object $f:A\to B$ here to this object; viz., $\langle !^\mathbf{Set}_A, !^\mathbf{Set}_B\rangle$, where $!^\mathbf{Set}_X:X\to \{*\}$ is the unique arrow from $X$ to the terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}$; at least from the "sets of the same size are essentially the same" point of view of category theory.
I know that terminal objects are unique up to isomorphism.
How do I prove that $\operatorname{id}_*$ is the terminal object here, if, indeed, I am correct?

I guess this is easy to do but I'm just not seeing it. I have done this exercise before, surely. It might be so obvious it's hard to pin down.

The generalization to presheaf categories is: if $\mathsf{C}$ is a small category, then the terminal object of $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}$ is the functor which maps every object to ${ * }$ and every morphism to the identity on ${ * }$.  (And even more generally, any limits or colimits are all constructed "pointwise".)

@Shaun (let me ask again because you deleted my previous comment, which maybe was a bit harsh) What did you try to solve this problem? Did you apply the definiton? What is your progress? Basically you already provided the required object and the unique morphism. What is left?

No, I get that I've said, essentially, that there's only one arrow.  I know that's what I need to prove, @MartinBrandenburg. How do I prove it? Because I'm getting lost in the "up to isomorphism" bit. I can see it as a terminal object; just not "the" terminal object, as far as isomorphisms go.

"The" terminal object is only defined up to (unique) isomorphism. You just need to prove that your proposed object is a terminal object, which you seem to already have, so what's your question?

You're nearly there. You've got the right object and you've got the right arrow into it, but you need to prove that there is only one such arrow.
To do that, just think about what an arrow into that object needs to be. It's a function $A\to \{*\}$ and a function $B\to \{*\}$ such that a certain square commutes. How many such maps exist? Well, how many maps $A\to \{*\}$ are there and how many maps $B\to \{*\}$ are there?
You said in a comment that you're getting lost in the "up to isomorphism" thing, so it's worth commenting on that: when it comes to morphisms, you don't really have to worry about it - a Hom-set is just a set, it's not defined up to iso, so you can ask whether one morphism is equal to another and that's always a well-defined question.
But the terminal object itself is unique only up to iso. You chose the object $\{*\}\to \{*\}$, but you could equally have chosen $\{\emptyset\}\to \{42\}$ or any other map between any pair of one-element sets. If it's not clear you should check that these all have the property of being terminal objects, and that they are all isomorphic.

You are correct that the identity $\{\star\} \to \{\star\}$ is the terminal object, since for every map of sets $X \to Y$ there is indeed a unique diagram
$$\require{amsCD}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y \\ @VVV @VVV \\ \{\star\} @>>> \{\star\}
\end{CD}$$
and it automatically commutes. This is because the maps to $\{\star\}$ are uniquely determined.
More generally, what we see here is that if $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object, then $\mathbf{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ has a terminal object as well, namely $\mathrm{id}_t : t \to t$ when $t \in \mathcal{C}$ is terminal.
You seem to be confused about the phrasing "find the terminal object". First of all, the meaning of "the" in category theory usually is "the object which is unique up to isomorphism". As in "the colimit" etc. Recall that terminal objects are not unique "on the nose", they are only unique up to isomorphism, in any category, including the morphism category. And moreover, any object which is isomorphic to a terminal object is also terminal.
All this means that once you have found one terminal object, you have found all of them. Just take the ones isomorphic to the one you found. In our case, the terminal objects of $\mathbf{Mor}(\mathbf{Set})$ are the (unique) maps $\{x\} \to \{y\}$ for two singleton sets $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$. And more generally, if $\mathcal{C}$ is any category with a  terminal object, the terminal objects in $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ are the (unique) morphisms $t \to t'$ where $t$ and $t'$ are (possibly different) terminal objects of $\mathcal{C}$.
See here for a generalization. Basically the "shape" of our diagrams does not matter here. For example, you could also define a category $\mathbf{ZigZag}(\mathcal{C})$ whose objects are morphisms $Z \to I \leftarrow G$, and whose morphisms are commutative diagrams
$$\require{amsCD}
\begin{CD}
Z @>>> I @<<< G \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
z @>>> a @<<< g \end{CD}$$
Again, the terminal objects are $t \to t' \leftarrow t''$ for terminal objects $t,t',t''$ of $\mathcal{C}$, but category theorists will usually say "the terminal object is $t \to t \leftarrow t$".
